# what is the origin of the phrase "labor force"

Tags: etymology

I am interested in the perspective based on a conversation that I had with a friend who alluded to the origin being related to he idea of forcing the people to work and then being altered to be more palatable like a force of nature

Comment: That sounds very implausible. Does your friend also think that "air force" originates with the idea of forcing people to fly?

Comment: I think your friend is misguided.  I think it comes from the same place that "armed forces" comes from- I.e., *A body of persons or other resources organized or available for a certain purpose* - [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/force)

Comment: Certainly *forced labor* means that. but that's an entirely different thing.

Comment: Did you find any definitions of "force" that might shed light on this question?  Please add them to your question or the question may be closed for lack of research.

Comment: Ask your friend to back up such a preposterous claim.

Answer (score 1):

The term ***force*** refers to a *body of persons,* from its original meaning "body of armed men":

***[Labour force](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/labor-force):***

> - work force.
> - (in the U.S.) the body of people who are at least 14 years old and are either employed or available for employment.

***[Force](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/force):***

> - A body of persons or other resources organized or available for a certain purpose: a large labor force.

From [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=force&allowed_in_frame=0):

***Force:***

> - Meaning "body of armed men, a military organization" first recorded late 14c. (also in Old French).

- The expression "labour force" dates back to 1880/85.